# Send DWORD through named pipe

Tags: c++, windows, named-pipes

Im trying to send a array of DWORDs over a named pipe but Im stuck trying to figure out how to send a single DWORD.
This is what I've got so far:

```
// Create a pipe to send data
HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        L"\\\\.\\pipe\\my_pipe",
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        NULL
    );

/* Waiting for the other side to connect and some error handling cut out */

//Here I try to send the DWORD  
DWORD msg = 0xDEADBEEF;
DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
result = WriteFile(
    pipe,
    (LPCVOID)msg, 
    sizeof(msg),
    &numBytesWritten, 
    NULL 
    );
```

But the `WriteFile(...)` call fails and returns `false`.

Receiving end:

```
/* CreateFile(...) */
DWORD msg[128];
DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
BOOL result = ReadFile(
    pipe,
    msg, 
    127 * sizeof(DWORD), 
    &numBytesRead, 
    NULL 
    );
```

Am I failing miserably or am I heading the right direction?

Comment: Plus one for msg=0xDEADBEEF, made me chuckle..and hungry. :) Also, I learned something after a quick google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = WriteFile(
    pipe,
    &msg, // <---- change this line
    sizeof(msg),
    &numBytesWritten, 
    NULL 
    );
```

When you cast, red flags should be going off in your head. In C++, a typesafe language, the moment you try to override types manually, you're off in the danger zone. `WriteFile` expects a pointer to data. You provided the data itself. Instead you should provide a pointer to the data.

Also, learn to use `GetLastError` to get more information when a call fails.

Comment: My hero and savior! Thank you, now I've managed to get it to work! EDIT: Pesky 5-min limit until I can accept an answer.